# Editing the path files for configuring make file

Tags: 12.04, make, paths, makefile

I installed a new software in my Ubuntu 12.04.
To install I downloaded it,and then do these in the terminal

```
cd ~/Downloads 

chmod +x gpucomputingsdk_4.2.9_linux.run

./gpucomputingsdk_4.2.9_linux.run
```

After installation at the last it showed in order to configure the make file I should do the following

```
PATH should be included with  /usr/local/cuda/bin

LD_LIBRARY_PATH should be included with /usr/local/cuda/lib
```

I was newbie, Can you please help me to do them permanently.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find complete install instructions for CUDA on the [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cuda).

Specifically for your question you have to append two lines to a (hidden) file `.bash_profile` in your home directory. This is accomplished by the following commands

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/cuda/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/cuda/lib:/opt/cuda/lib64' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

In both lines the `>>` is **important** to append to that file and not to overwrite it.

The text

> Update variables, and this on every boot:

is misleading. It should say

> Update the variables **now** (lines 1, 2) and automatically at every reboot (lines 3, 4).